# Equivalent to Azure Queue on Windows Server

Tags: azure, queue

I have a need to implement an architecture which might be delivered on Azure but also has to run on a standard Windows Server. There is a direct correllation between Microsoft AppFabric Distributed Caching and the Azure Cache, but what technology could you recommend to proivide similar functionality to the Azure Queue on Windows Server.

I have three candidates 
1) MSMQ
2) SQL Server Service Broker.
3) RabbitMQ.

The first is deprecated and the second requires a heavyweight SQL Server installation, and the third is popular but I dont have direct experience of it. Are there any other candidate technologies that I should consider ? (hopefully Microsoft just for tidy-ness, but I'd consider others).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at [Service Bus for Windows Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282144.aspx)? It does still require a SQL DB, but you can use SQL Express 2008 R2 and higher.